# Objective-C and C++ Mixed compilation error “_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIResponder”

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

When I change `PlatFormFactory.cpp` to `PlatFormFactory.mm` [image]

How can I compile successfully?

My core code is as blow, I wan't call Objective-C Object in C++

`IOSCallBack.mm` :

```
#include "IUdpCallBack.h"
#import "RicUDP_ObjC_Client.h"
@class RicUDP_ObjC_Client;

IOSCallBack::IOSCallBack()
    {
        m_pCallBack = NULL;
    }

    IOSCallBack::~IOSCallBack()
    {
        m_pCallBack = NULL;
    }

    void IOSCallBack::SetCallBack(void* pCallBack)
    {
        m_pCallBack = (__bridge RicUDP_ObjC_Client *)pCallBack;
    }

    void IOSCallBack::on_notify_mqttaddr(const char *szAddr, int port, const char *topic)
    {
        printf("%s\n", szAddr);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed similar issue when embedded Objective-C source to a project which is generate by Unity by setting OTHER_LDFLAGS build settings to `-ObjC, -WI, -undefined, -dynamic_lookup` flags (row Target) and OTHER_LDFLAGS build settings to `-ObjC` flag (row Project).